# How to show specific viewController in AppDelegate when receive notification?

Tags: swift, appdelegate

[![enter image description here][1]][1]I am now working on voip call app in swift. This app use user authentication when app is opened.
So UINavigationController is the rootViewController of main window and loginViewController is the rootViewcontroller of the navigation controller.
After login, app shows main screen of call history.
But now I want to show call screen when notification is received and app is in background.

How can I do this?

Comment: Are you receiving notifications through the didReceiveNotification function inside of appDelegate?

Comment: Yes, I receive notifications in appDelegate, but not in didReceiveNotification function. I am using PKPushRegistry, so I receive notifications in didReceiveIncomingPushWith function in AppDelegate.swift

Comment: And you are setting your initial view controller using code inside SceneDelegate, right?

Comment: But you can assume I receive notification in didReceiveNotification and show viewcontroller in that function.

Comment: I didn't set initial view controller in AppDelegate or SceneDelegate, just defined in storyboard

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your storyboard with the View Controllers labeled, just so I can get a clear idea of how it is structured before I provide you with an answer?